# How to connect to SQL server 2000 from SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I need to connect to a SQL server 2000 Database from SQL server 2008.

```
SQL server 2000 properties:
ServerName:WinxpV1\SQL2k
UserName:Raymond
password:xxxxx
Computer Ip address:192.168.100.124
```

And I'm trying to connect to it using following method:

```
File-->Connect to:
ServerName:WinxpV1\SQL2k
Authentication:SQL server Authentication
Login:Raymond
Password:xxxxx
```

TCP/IP is enable in "SQL server utility" in SQL2000. but I can't connect to it.

Comment: Are you trying to set up a linked server?  Or connect to the server in Management Studio?

Comment: Is the server actually a named instance?  (the \sql2k bit after the server name...)

Comment: I'm not sure, when I installed it, it was "WinxpV1\SQL2k". I haven't worked ever with SQL 2000 version.

Comment: Try connecting with just the server name.  Wild shot in the dark...  Do you have a copy of SQL 2000's Enterprise Manager available?

Comment: I tried it but doesn't connect. Yes I have Enter prise Manager

Comment: I can connect in SQL 2000 Enterprise manager directly with user name and password I mentioned above. but can't connect remotely to it.

Comment: Is it refusing your connection, or just not finding it?

Comment: This is the Error message:`

Cannot connect to winxpv1\sql2k.


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476
`

Comment: I can connect to a SQL server 2005 easily with Linked server or from Connect menu. but I can't connect to SQL server2000 version

Answer (score 1):

Can you use linked servers?

```
Exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server=N'WinxpV1\SQL2k'
  , @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' --I'm guessing here
  , @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
  , @provstr=(Your connection string here)
```

You can use sp_addlinkedsrvlogin if you can't pass your credentials in the connection string.  Here's a good site for connection strings too: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ (I have no affiliation with this site; I have found it helpful on many occasions.)

Comment: I tried this but it just brings a Default database with no tables:`Exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server=N'WinxpV1\SQL2k'
  , @srvproduct=N'' --I'm guessing here
  , @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
  , @provstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=WinxpV1\SQL2k;UID=raymond;PWD=xxxx;'`

Comment: Ok, what about adding `Initial Catalog=(your database name)` to your connection string?